# PlantUML port position in component diagram

Tags: plantuml

Here is my code and how it is rendered

```
@startuml
skinparam componentStyle rectangle
component A1 {
   port P1
   [E1]
   [E2]
   [E1] -r-> [E2]
   [E2] -r-> P1
}
component A2 {
   port P2
   [E1] as e
   P2 -r-> e
}
P1 -r-> P2
@enduml
```

[image]

How to make P1 and P2 are on the vertical edges of A1 and A2 respectively?
Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `left to right direction` and remove the explicit direction on the arrows.

```
left to right direction

skinparam componentStyle rectangle
component A1 {
   port P1
   [E1]
   [E2]
   [E1] --> [E2]
   [E2] --> P1
}
component A2 {
   port P2
   [E1] as e
   P2 --> e
}
P1 --> P2
```

[image]