# PlantUML - How to position the ports on the right side of a component?

Tags: uml, diagram, plantuml, component-diagram

[I am trying to position the 5 ports on the right side of the WebServer so that the name wont be covered by the lines but I have failed - click to see the diagram that i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4Aou.png)

I am using PlantUml.
Here is my code

```
@startuml
    
     
    component "WebServer" as WS {
    port " " as P21
    port " " as P22
    port " " as P23
    port " " as P24
    port " " as P25

    component "Web-GUI" as WG {
        port " " as P11
        port " " as P12
        port " " as P13
        port " " as P14
        port " " as P15
    }
}



     ' Connections between ports
    P21 -right- P11
    P22 -right- P12
    P23 -right- P13
    P24 -right- P14
    P25 -right- P15

@enduml
```

[This is what I am trying to do - click to see the diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkPqX.png)

Comment: Did you have a look at "left to right direction" ? see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/72700128/1657886as an example. Maybe do also a search on the Internet for "plantuml port position".

Comment: Yes i tried it but I does not work for me. Thank you alot for the answer!